# How to get data from database in javascript array and display it by using document.write() method

Tags: javascript, arrays

[image]

In the above i attached my database image (front-end). i want to fetch those data as arrays in javascript also need to show it by using documet.write() method.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does your data look like, where do you get it from and why you need to use document write?

Comment: That was the sample image ,actually i am working with country,state array function ,i just want to know how to display it by using  write method in js

Comment: You need to create an HTML template and then inject that string into the document using `document.write( yourTemplate )`... you are missing the basics of web developing it would seem.

Comment: i am not asking for the basics,i want to know whether there is any specific function for it or not

Answer (score 1):

You provided so little context so I'm gonna make some assumptions on my side.

First I'd like to assume you have to the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) api. We'll be using that to *fetch* the data, I'm gonna assume too that you have access to [ES6 features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_2015_support_in_Mozilla) and are familiar with [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). And finally, I'm assuming that the data returned is in JSON format.

Here's the solution:

```
window.fetch('<insert-url-here>')
  .then(response => reponse.json())
  .then(data => data.forEach(d => document.write(d));
```